# Return the value out of a group of columns based on another column's location

Tags: r

I'm trying to pull in the value out of a group of columns based on the  another column. Walking through the first row for an example:
-Take value of `CodeToMatch` = 1
-Search through columns: `Code.1`, `Code.2`, `Code.3` to locate where the value of 1 is. In this case, it's in the 3rd column, therefore, return the value of the 3rd column out of `pCode.1`, `pCode.2`, `pCode3`, which is "p4"

The `expected_outcome` column in my example df below shows what I'm after.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
c1 <- c("1","2","3")
c2 <- c("8","1","3")
c3 <- c("4","2","4")
c4 <- c("1","3","5")
c5 <- c("p1","p2","p3")
c6 <- c("p8","p1","p3")
c7 <- c("p4","p2","p4")
c8 <- c("p4","p1","p3")
df <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8)
colnames(df)[c(1:8)] <- c("CodeToMatch","Code.1","Code.2","Code.3","pCode.1","pCode.2","pCode.3","expected_output")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data.table solution

**sample data**

```
df <- structure(list(CodeToMatch = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3"), class = "factor"), Code.1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"3", "8"), class = "factor"), Code.2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("2", "4"), class = "factor"), Code.3 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1", 
"3", "5"), class = "factor"), pCode.1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("p1", 
"p2", "p3"), class = "factor"), pCode.2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("p1", "p3", "p8"), class = "factor"), pCode.3 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("p2", "p4"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

**code**

```
library(data.table)
#first, melt wide table to long format
df.melt <- melt( setDT(df), id.vars="CodeToMatch", measure.vars = patterns(Code="^Code\\..*", pCode="^pCode.*"))
#now finding everything is easy...
df.melt[ Code == CodeToMatch, .(CodeToMatch, pCode)]
```

**output**

```
#    CodeToMatch pCode
# 1:           3    p3
# 2:           2    p1
# 3:           1    p4
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got no idea how well this generalises but here is an option

```
nCode <- 3
df$expected_output <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x[nCode + 1 + which(x[2:(nCode + 1)] == x[1])])
df$expected_output
#[1] "p4" "p1" "p3"
```

Note that the number of "code" columns is hard-coded. In your case you have 3 `"Code"` columns with matching `"pCode"` columns. Adjust as necessary. This also assumes that the first column always contains the to-be-matched code numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the code and pCode columns based on the pattern in the names. Find out the index of `CodeToMatch` which lies in `code_columns` for every row and extract the corresponding `pcode_columns` from it using `mapply`.

```
code_columns <- grep("^Code\\.[0-9]+", names(df))
pcode_columns <- grep("^pCode", names(df))

mapply(function(x, y) df[x, pcode_columns][df[x, code_columns]==y],
                       1:nrow(df), df$CodeToMatch)

#[1] "p4" "p1" "p3"
```

Ran

```
df[1:4] <- lapply(df[1:4], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

to keep numeric columns as numeric and not factors.